# Has anyone tried using some custom drill bit for can openers?

Tags: substitute-tool, kitchen, efficiency

Just wondering if anyone has come up with a drill bit attachment that could operate handle for can opener? Yes, I'm lazy! But on those special occasions when I have to open a bunch of veggies and fruit cans I wish I had something.

[image]

Comment: You *do* know there are electric can openers, even ones small enough to use in hand like the one pictured above, right?

Comment: Yeah, just wondering if there were any creative ideas to turn the handle with a drill somehow.

Comment: If you want a drill bit that can attach to a can opener, I can 3D print you a Carbon Fiber one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. Someone jury rigged one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eK630Qm9I8

Although that video makes it look pretty smooth, manually applying power to a can opener, especially without rev control (I own that particular model of Bosch Ixo and can confirm that it doesn't), can get out of hand and might turn messy.

However, if you want to be able to open a lot of cans I would get a dedicated **electric can opener**, these can sometimes be attached to the side of the countertop: https://www.google.com/search?q=electric+can+opener

They're fairly simple and affordable devices, various kinds [have been around for almost a century](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/11/dont-lose-a-finger-the-200-year-evolution-of-the-can-opener/).

Comment: Note, that's a very low power screwdriver more than a drill. If you did that with a full-spec drill, you'd be wearing a lot of can's contents, if it didn't break your wrist first.

Comment: Yep, hence the warning.